# Business Rules and DDD Domain behavior in Ubiquitous Language?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have a situation where I am modelling a domain, the business rule of the domain is that

> When a user needs to see categories.. the user should see both account
>   and store categories. Because the Store Inherits Categories from the
>   main Account.

What would be the best way to include this business rule in the damain model keeping Ubiquitous Language in mind?

here is what I had in mind

```
Store.InheritCategoriesFrom(Account.Categories);
Store.GetAllCategories();
```

and then in the behavior function in the domain can be like

```
public List<Category> AllCategories { get; set; }

public InheritCategoriesFrom(List<Category> AccountCategories)
{
      //code to merge Shop.Categories with Account Categories into AllCategories  here..

}

public List<Category> GetAllCategories()
{
      return AllCategories;
}
```

Please let me know if i am wrong and why? So I can start thinking in the right direction.

Comment: From the limited information it looks okay.  I'd suggest maybe making `AllCategories` a private field.  From a DDD perspective, I'd question the word 'inherits' as being a term I wouldn't naturally expect the business to use and terms like 'Account', 'Store' and 'Category' are too generic for my liking.  As someone who knows nothing of your domain, they don't reveal any domain knowledge.  E.g. should they be 'UserAccount', 'DataStore', 'ProductCategory'?  Or maybe 'CreditAccount', 'WalmartStore', 'GoodsCategory'? etc.

Comment: +1 inherit doesn't seem like a very domain-specific term. Plus, if it's just readonly stuff, I wouldn't bother crafting a nice rich model around it. You can just get the `AccountCategories` and `StoreCategories`from the domain layer (or directly from DB if you use CQRS) and merge them to get the right view model.

Comment: right apologies for that, an Account is what i used for the term the domain expert is using to explain a BusinessAccount (thanks for pointing that out to me) a business like Walmart, can have many stores... e.g WebStore, Central Station Store. A Business Account can have many categories of its products that it sells in every store, but the store manager is allowed to add more products (of different categories) that would be special to his store. So the shop would display, all categories of products.. (i hope this makes more sense)

Comment: The domain model is much more about processing commands than query convenience. That's not a problem I would solve in the domain at all.

Answer (score 2):

> When a user needs to see categories.. the user should ***see*** both account and store categories.

That's not a business rule, that's a UI view requirement => view model data => can be queried directly from the db and it doesn't have to be one query only.

> Because the Store Inherits Categories from the main Account.

That's an implementation detail, it can't be a *business* rule and a useless detail nevertheless (even harmful) when talking about querying.

Just have a method on your store (or use a [query handler](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/10/29/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-gets-and-queries/)) which will return all the data required for the view model. No inheritance needed. Just KISS.